# Player Movement and Camera Rotation not happening together in Godot 3D

Tags: 3d, godot4

I am trying to make a sort of `3D first-person maze running game` in `Godot 4.2.1` where the player `moves with WASD` and `camera turns with mouse movement`.
For the movement, I am using the Godot `CharacterBody3D` along with the provided movement template script. Following is the code for the head turn:

```
func _unhandled_input(event: InputEvent) -> void:
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        Input.mouse_mode = Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED
    elif event.is_action_pressed("ui_cancel"):
        Input.mouse_mode = Input.MOUSE_MODE_VISIBLE
        
    if Input.mouse_mode == Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED:
        if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
            rotate_y(-event.relative.x * 0.006)
            camera.rotate_x(-event.relative.y * 0.006)
            camera.rotation.x = clamp(camera.rotation.x, deg_to_rad(-30), deg_to_rad(60))
```

And for the 3D movement and jump:

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    # Add the gravity.
    if not is_on_floor():
        velocity.y -= gravity * delta


    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_accept") and is_on_floor():
        velocity.y = JUMP_VELOCITY

    var input_dir = Input.get_vector("left", "right", "up", "down")
    var direction = (neck.transform.basis * Vector3(input_dir.x, 0, input_dir.y)).normalized()
    if direction:
        velocity.x = direction.x * SPEED
        velocity.z = direction.z * SPEED
    else:
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, SPEED)
        velocity.z = move_toward(velocity.z, 0, SPEED)

    move_and_slide()
```

Everything works fine but the problem is that only one of the functions work at a time, which means I can't simultaneously turn my head and move.

I tried to transfer one of the functions to a separate Node, so that maybe they would run together but that didn't work.
I want to know a way where both the functions could work simultaneously.
Please share if you have the answer.
Thanks!

Comment: How does the other function look like? Edit: my current hypothesis is that you do not want to use `_unhandled_input` but use `_input` instead.

Comment: No, doesn't work, and also I have edited the post to include both functions...

Comment: Reading the code, I don't see how it can be an input problem. So new hypothesis: moving the camera is causing `is_on_floor` to fail. Possible solution: move `move_and_slide` to the start of `_physics_process`, so the `is_on_floor` checks happen after (essentially you compute the velocity one frame, and move the next).

Comment: Well, I got it. The solution was to use `_input ` instead of `_unhandled_input`. There was actually a third function which wasn't supposed to interfere with the input but it did and caused the trouble. Anyways, thanks for the help.

Comment: You can go ahead and write an asnwer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

So,
The solution was to use `_input()` in place of `_unhandled_input()`.
This way both the movement and head rotation would happen at the same time.